# Open source conference platform

Tags: open-source, web-apps

I'm looking for an open-source conference software project that does the following:

1. Sell tickets to attendees
2. Accept and manage session proposals
3. Perform scheduling / agenda building

Ideally, I'm looking for an OSS project that:

- I can contribute development to
- Has active development already

Answer (score 2):

I have not used this, but I have attended conferences where I am pretty sure it has been used. There is a Drupal distribution called COD: http://usecod.com/ and https://www.drupal.org/project/cod . The following quotes are from the usecod.com marketing page.

Ticket sales:

> Sell tickets to your attendees with Drupal Commerce support ready to go

(EDIT: Dealing with sales/commerce will likely be the hardest part, but this is probably true regardless of what open source solution you choose.)

Session proposals:

> Moderate and manage session selection

Perform scheduling:

> Drag & Drop Scheduling
>
> Easily schedule session across different days and rooms

The COD project itself was updated in October, so still seems under active development. Drupal as a whole has a pretty active community. It is also easy to contribute to the project (many people start by reporting issues and submitting patches).

The downside is that Drupal has a high learning curve. Using a distribution rather than starting from scratch might make the process less painful, however.